# OpenMP false sharing and cache hits exploitation

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix, parallel-processing, openmp

In my code there are several methods that contain nested loops for moving in a ny*nx matrix. I wanted to parallelise the process so I used something like this on every method:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(jj,x_e,x_w,y_n,y_s)
  for(ii=0;ii<ny;ii++) {
    for(jj=0;jj<nx;jj++) {
      /* determine indices of axis-direction neighbours
      ** respecting periodic boundary conditions (wrap around) */
      y_n = (ii + 1) % ny;
      x_e = (jj + 1) % nx;
      y_s = (ii == 0) ? (ii + ny - 1) : (ii - 1);
      x_w = (jj == 0) ? (jj + nx - 1) : (jj - 1);
      //propagate densities to neighbouring cells, following
      tmp[ii *nx + jj].speeds[0]  = cells[ii*nx + jj].speeds[0]; /* central cell, */
                                                                                     /* no movement   */
      tmp[ii *nx + x_e].s[1] = cells[ii*nx + jj].s[1]; /* east */
      tmp[y_n*nx + jj].s[2]  = cells[ii*nx + jj].s[2]; /* north */
      tmp[ii *nx + x_w].s[3] = cells[ii*nx + jj].s[3]; /* west */
      tmp[y_s*nx + jj].s[4]  = cells[ii*nx + jj].s[4]; /* south */
      tmp[y_n*nx + x_e].s[5] = cells[ii*nx + jj].s[5]; /* north-east */
      tmp[y_n*nx + x_w].s[6] = cells[ii*nx + jj].s[6]; /* north-west */
      tmp[y_s*nx + x_w].s[7] = cells[ii*nx + jj].s[7]; /* south-west */      
      tmp[y_s*nx + x_e].s[8] = cells[ii*nx + jj].s[8]; /* south-east */      
    }
  }
```

This piece of code (and the others aswell) is, however, very slow. Is there any way that I can correct my #pragma statement and rewrite the data structure or the loop to make it cache friendly and avoid false sharing?

PS: The code is compiled with `-O3` so every attempt at minor optimization didn't achieve any speed up.

Comment: What is the orignal data structure of `tmp` and `cells`? How large are `nx` and `ny`?

Comment: tmp and cells are identical, they are arrays of structures. each struct contains a double array s (size 9). nx and ny are 200 and 300 in my basic experiment but they can go up to 2000 and 3000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up the threads and distributing work to them will introduce some overhead. Since you have a small work size (200x300), and the work is simple (only some data copy), the threading overhead can be even larger than your actual work, that's one of the reasons that you don't get performance improvement.

Another reason is that your code has poor cache localization due to the use of array of structures (AoS). Especially when you are writing to `tmp`. For better cache hit performance you could consider use structure of arrays (SoA). In fact you only need to exchange the dimensions from

```
cells[nx*ny][9]
```

to

```
cells[9][nx*ny]
```

Then you will find part of the copy can be done with `memcpy()` directly.

On the other hand, I don't think your code has serious false sharing problem.

Comment: While switching from AoS to SoA would definitely improve the speed of that particular loop operation, it might negatively affect other parts of the code that are not shown.

Comment: You could consider simply use `new double[9*nx*ny]`

Comment: i have to do this in c

Comment: so i create a regular pointer but i use the matrix notation in this way cells[9][nx*ny]

Comment: if i use malloc i can't use the [][] notation anymore cause i get an error "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector". If i create it using cells[9][nx*ny] somehow its fine for a 30x20 version but i get segmentation fault on the 300x200 version immediately, even if i try to write in cells[0][0]

Comment: You may have to use 1-D index like `cells[(3 * ny + ii) * nx + jj]`

Comment: done, unfortunately it goes slower. it would be nice to use the SoA, if only i had defined nx and ny. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You changed the data structure but nothing else? That of course won't improve the performance. try to copy the data one direction by another. the first one could be `memcpy(tmp + (0 * ny + 0) * nx + 0, cells + (0 * ny + 0) * nx + 0, nx*ny*sizeof(double));`

Answer (score 0):

False sharing occurs when shared cache lines are being modified, i.e. being written to. Given that, you would greatly improve the locality of your code's memory access pattern by simply inverting the operation: instead of performing a scatter operation at each element of `cells`, do a gather operation at each element of `tmp`:

```
tmp[ii*nx + jj].s[0] = cells[ii*nx + jj].s[0];
tmp[ii*nx + jj].s[1] = cells[...].s[1];
...
tmp[ii*nx + jj].s[8] = cells[...].s[8];
```

That way you'll linearise the memory write pattern of each thread, making it much more cache friendly and reducing false sharing at the same time.

Also note that your code's performance is mostly limited by the memory bandwidth and therefore for large arrays you might not get any speed-up with more than one thread unless doing so provides more memory bandwidth, e.g. you have a multisocket system with each socket having its own memory controller and each thread executes on cores in different sockets. Your tests with `nx` of 200 and `ny` of 300 already requires at least 8,2 MiB of memory and hardly fits in the last-level cache of most desktop processors but still fits in the cache of most server class CPUs. The bigger 2000 x 3000 case is memory-bound for sure.